# How to have a batch file echo an alert if a chosen file is updated while the batch is running?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to make my batch file echo an alert if a certain file updates, but have no idea what to do for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to (re)start your monitoring

```
for %%i in (filename) do set snapshot=%%~ti
```

When you want to check whether the file has been updated,

```
for %%i in (filename) do if not "%snapshot%"=="%%~ti" ECHO file was updated
```